# Rails 3 Active Record relation order: Use hash instead of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

To sort a relation in Rails 3, we have to do this:

```
User.where(:activated => true).order('id ASC')
```

But I think this:

```
User.where(:activated => true).order(:id => :asc)
```

would make better sense because the way the field name be escaped should depend on the adapter (`SqlLite vs Mysql vs PostgreSQL`), right?

Is there something similar to that?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there's no option for this syntax built into ActiveRecord, but it shouldn't be hard for you to add one. I found the `order` method defined in `lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb`. Theoretically, you should be able to do something like this:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module QueryMethods
    def order(*args)
      args.map! do |arg|
        if arg.is_a? Hash
          # Format a string out of the hash that matches the original AR style
          stringed_arg
        else
          arg
        end
      end

      super
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the key problem is: **ActiveRecord API is not aware of ordering semantic**. It just accepts a string and bypasses to the underlying database. Fortunately, Sqlite, MySQL and PostgreSQL has no difference in `order` syntax.

I don't think ActiveRecord can do this abstraction well, and it doesn't need to do it. It works well with relation databases, but is hard to integrate with NoSQL, eg. MongoDB.

[DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/), another famous Ruby ORM, did better abstraction. [Take a look at its query syntax](http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html):

```
@zoos_by_tiger_count = Zoo.all(:order => [ :tiger_count.desc ])
```

The API is aware of the ordering semantic. By default, DataMapper will generate SQL order statement:

https://github.com/datamapper/dm-do-adapter/blob/master/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb#L626-634

```
def order_statement(order, qualify)
  statements = order.map do |direction|
    statement = property_to_column_name(direction.target, qualify)
    statement << ' DESC' if direction.operator == :desc
    statement
  end

  statements.join(', ')
end
```

However, it's possible to override at DB adapter layer:

https://github.com/solnic/dm-mongo-adapter/blob/master/lib/dm-mongo-adapter/query.rb#L260-264

```
def sort_statement(conditions)
  conditions.inject([]) do |sort_arr, condition|
    sort_arr << [condition.target.field, condition.operator == :asc ? 'ascending' : 'descending']
  end
end
```

---

TL;DR:

- You don't need worry about syntax problem if you are only using SqlLite, Mysql and PostgreSQL.
- For better abstraction, you can try DataMapper.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, you could drop the 'ASC' bit as ordering in all database is implicitly ascending

```
Foo.order(:bar)
```

I am aware that this doesn't cover the case where you'd want to do `order by bar desc` but actually for order by this doesn't matter much unless you are using functions for the order by clause in which case maybe something like [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) would help