# How do you sort a collection by distant relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a tree-like relationship model with a fixed depth, and each level has a code attribute - similar to this;

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :sub_categories

  default_scope order(:code)
end

class SubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :category
  has_many    :items

  def self.sorted
    self.joins(:category).order('"categories".code ASC, "sub_categories".code')
  end
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sub_category

  def self.sorted
    # what goes here?
  end
end
```

`Category.all` gets all the the categories ordered by `categories.code`.

`SubCategory.sorted` gets all the sub_categories ordered by `categories.code, sub_categories.code`.  I used this approach because `default_scope : joins(:categories).order('categories.code, sub_categories.code')` makes `.find` return read-only records.

I would like to call `Items.sorted` and get the all items ordered by `categories.code, sub_categories.code, items.code` but I can't figure out how.  I imagine I need a second .joins, but I don't have a relationship name to supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sub_category

  def self.sorted
    # do not need self here as that is implied
    joins(sub_category: :category).
    order('"categories".code ASC, "sub_categories".code, "items".code')
  end
end
```

See the docs for joining nested assoications [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-nested-associations-single-level)

Comment: This was one of my first ideas, but I haven't been able to make it work.  I don't believe that `has_one, :through` can work with a `belongs_to` relationship...the references are not in the right places.  I get a `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError` when calling `@items.each`

Comment: Did not know that..learned something...updated the answer with a different solution

Comment: this is a big improvement over what I had, but is there also a way to improve the order call?  Explicitly naming the tables and columns doesn't seem like the rails way...i would expect something like order(categories: :code, sub_categories: :code, :code) would work loosen the coupling to the database.

Comment: I don't think that kind of syntax exits for `order` see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138008/rails-3-active-record-relation-order-use-hash-instead-of-string) and the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering)

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it seems like there should be a better way;

```
def self.sorted
  joins(:sub_category).
    joins('INNER JOIN "categories" on "categories".id = "sub_categories".category_id').
    order('"categories".code ASC, "sub_categories".code ASC, "items".number ASC')
end
```